# ML pipeline for dataflow and DataflowPythonJobOp's support custom docker containers?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-vertex-ai, google-ai-platform, vertex-ai-pipeline

I use customer docker containers to run dataflow jobs. I want to chain it together with my tpu training job etc, so I'm considering running kubeflow pipeline on vertex ai. Is this a sensible idea? (There seems to be many alternatives like airflow etc.)

In particular, must I use [DataflowPythonJobOp](https://google-cloud-pipeline-components.readthedocs.io/en/google-cloud-pipeline-components-2.0.0/api/v1/dataflow.html#v1.dataflow.DataflowPythonJobOp) in the pipeline? It does not seem to support custom worker images. I assume I can just have one small machine, which launches the dataflow pipeline and stays idle (besides writing some logs) until the dataflow pipeline finishes?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to pass the custom container args with https://google-cloud-pipeline-components.readthedocs.io/en/google-cloud-pipeline-components-2.0.0/api/v1/dataflow.html#v1.dataflow.DataflowPythonJobOp.args?

Comment: custom container at best is only used at workers? if my `python_module_path` refers to custom libraries or pip packages not found on gcpc (google cloud platform component) image, launching the dataflow job (which happens on gcpc) will fail in the first place?

Comment: You could move the import parts inside the Beam pipeline to avoid the launching error.

Comment: @bill - Have you managed to sort it out .I also have the same requirement .If I use https://google-cloud-pipeline-components.readthedocs.io/en/google-cloud-pipeline-components-2.0.0/api/v1/dataflow.html#v1.dataflow.DataflowPythonJobOp vertex AI pipeline fails as it tries to pull Apache Beam from pypi.org .We don't have access to public repo .Even if I create a container image for the dataflow pipeline and use it in pipeline options , it still gets stuck in the 'from apache_beam import PipelineOptions' . As it does not have apache beam in GCPC